# .Append not working

Tags: jquery

**What i am trying to do is append the Table and its contents after **test123*** that is before `</span>` tag is closed, but its not working, not sure what is wrong in this code ?*

**JQUERY CODE**

```
$('span[itemprop="description"]').append($('C1'));
```

**HTML CODE**

```
  <span itemprop='description'>test123</span>
        this is outside of span tag<br>

     <table width="200" border="1" class="C1">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: also `append` is appending the stuff into your span element not after it

Comment: maybe it's just the . missing : `$('.C1')` to get the elements of class C1? Is that what you were trying to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot a `.`:

```
$('span[itemprop="description"]').append($('.C1'));
```

Comment: @user580950 i said it too so why i am down-voted.??? even this will not work because it will get object not html inside of it..

Comment: @Dipesh Parmar [Read the docs](http://api.jquery.com/append/), you can use a jquery object as the argument.

Answer (score 1):

`itemprop` isn't a valid HTML attribute. I'm not sure if jQuery would allow this to work in the first place. You'll want to use `data-itemprop` instead.

`$('C1')` suggests you have an (again invalid) `<C1>` element. You need to use `$('.C1')` to select on the class.

Comment: Does that even matter, the code works for what he tries to do. The question is not if this is valid HTML

Comment: @s.lenders: I was editing my answer when you replied. I had previously given an invalid answer as I thought this was a different question, so had to quickly edit it. And yes, invalid HTML *does* matter as it's bad practice and there's no need for it.

Comment: Also I'm not sure why this was downvoted, along with every other answer to this question...

Answer (score 1):

C1 isn't a valid selector. you need to use

```
$('span[itemprop="description"]').append($('.C1'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('span[itemprop="description"]').append($('.C1').clone());
```

You missed to define `class` in selector add `.` . Also you are appending Object to span not a html so i used `.clone` and its works for me.

Comment: explain down-vote..no matter if its not a HTML attribute but we can still select it...try it..it always works.

Answer (score 0):

You should append the html, not the object. You can do like this:

```
$('span[itemprop=description]').append($('.C1').html());
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the jQuery code to :

```
$('span[itemprop="description"]').append($('.C1'));
```